# How do I switch my visual studio project from a project properties tab to a AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm following a tutorial that requires pasting a specific line of code into AssemblyInfo.cs, but I can't see it or the properties object it's supposed to be in. I'm able to access a GUI in visual studio that changes certain parts of the project properties, but that's about it. I found out that I can set the project so that the settings in the GUI will be converted into a AssemblyInfo.cs file when the project is built, but I clicked build and it didn't appear. I'm guessing this option creates that file once the solution is exported, but I need it to be converted before that so I can follow the tutorial's step. I'm using a .net framework with a class library.